# Pass this element into a function from ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass `this` element to my validator. Tried `this`, but it passes a scope of the controller. How to change the code to get into my `div`?

```
<div data-ng-class="!validators.headerImageValidator(this) ? 'has-error' : ''"></div>
```

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: I want to get `div` element in my function `headerImageValidator`, but I can use `jQuery` if necessary

Comment: You should only do DOM manipulation in directives. What are you trying to  do exactly? Why do you need a reference to an element?

Comment: @Nickon what do you mean by this? is it `DOM` or any `context`?

Comment: I have an image input inside the div. I want mark the div with error class when the image is null or chosen image is incorrect in some way

Comment: Try to write directive, which will be responsible for validation. From the directive you will have access to the element.

Comment: @Niezbor Sounds like a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write directive, which will be responsible for validation. From the directive you will have access to the element.